# Numba python CUDA vs. cuBLAS speed difference on simple operations

Tags: python, cuda, numba

I'm profiling some code and can't figure out a performance discrepancy. I'm trying to do a simple element-wise addition between two arrays (in-place). This is the CUDA kernel using numba:

```
from numba import cuda

@cuda.jit('void(float32[:], float32[:])')
def cuda_add(x, y):

    ix = cuda.threadIdx.x + cuda.blockIdx.x * cuda.blockDim.x
    stepSize = cuda.gridDim.x * cuda.blockDim.x
    while ix < v0.shape[0]:
        y[ix] += x[ix]
        ix += stepSize
```

I thought the performance was fine, but then I compared it to the cuBLAS method:

```
from accelerate.cuda.blas import Blas

blas = Blas()
blas.axpy(1.0, X, Y)
```

The performance of the BLAS method is roughly 25% faster for large arrays (20M elements). This is after "warming up"  the `cuda.jit` kernel by previously calling it so the compiled PTX code is already cached (not sure if this matters but did it just to make sure that wasn't the issue).

I could understand this performance difference for level 3 matrix-matrix operations, but this is a simple addition. Is there something i can do to squeeze more performance out of the cuda.jit code? I'm asking because the real code I want to optimize is a 2d array, which can't be passed to blas.axpy.

**EDIT** Execution code and other needed packages:

```
import numpy as np

def main():
    n = 20 * 128 * 128 * 64
    x = np.random.rand(n).astype(np.float32)
    y = np.random.rand(n).astype(np.float32)

    ##  Create necessary GPU arrays
    d_x = cuda.to_device(x)
    d_y = cuda.to_device(y)

    ##  My function
    cuda_add[1024, 64](d_x , d_y)

    ##  cuBLAS function
    blas = Blas()
    blas.axpy(1.0, d_x , d_y)
```

Comment: If you are going to post code, could you at least make sure it compiles? And execution arguments are critical to performance in a simple kernel like this, but you haven't shown them. Could you fix this please?

Comment: Is that really your execution arguments? 64 threads per block and 1024 blocks?

Comment: yes, but i've tried other combinations of TPB and blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The very short answer is no. CUBLAS leverages a number of things (textures, vector types) to improve the performance of memory bound code like this which the numba CUDA dialect doesn't presently support.

I dashed off this in CUDA:

```
__device__ float4 add(float4 x, float4 y) 
{
    x.x += y.x; x.y += y.y; x.z += y.z; x.w += y.w; 
    return x;
} 

__global__ void mykern(float* x, float* y, int N)
{
    float4* x4 = reinterpret_cast<float4*>(x);
    float4* y4 = reinterpret_cast<float4*>(y);

    int strid = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;
    int tid = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;

    for(; tid < N/4; tid += strid) {
        float4 valx = x4[tid];
        float4 valy = y4[tid];
        y4[tid] = add(valx, valy);
    }       
}
```

and my benchmarking shows it to be within about 5% of CUBLAS, but I don't believe you can do that in numba at the moment.

As an aside, I don't understand your remark about not being able to run `saxpy` on a 2D array. If you arrays are contiguous in memory (as I suspect they must be) and have the same layout (i.e. not trying to add a transpose), then you *can* use `saxpy` on a 2D array.